# jQuery siblings selector problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have this small script:

http://jsfiddle.net/gmAjC/

```
<input name="n1" value="test">
<br/><span></span>
<br/>
<span style="background-color:red">after input</span>
```

and here is the js:

```
$('input[name=n1] ~ span:first').html('new content');
```

it works fine until I change 'br' (after input) to 'p'. Is this a jQuery bug or my query is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you put a <p>, then the span will not be an sibling any more.

Comment: **Tip:** *Always inspect the generated HTML*. Then you would have noticed the `<p />` tag and which problems it creates (`<p>` is not a self closing tag). So the answer is: Neither it is a bug nor the selector is wrong. Your HTML was.

Comment: The example you gave in this question (not in the fiddle) works as expected. It selects the first span sibling appearing after the input, and sets the content to `"new content"`. That span is the empty span you've added after the `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the HTML you had in that jsFiddle

```
<span style="background-color:red">before input</span><p/>
<input name="n1" value="test">
<br/><span></span>
<span style="background-color:red">after input</span>
```

If I get rid of the `<p/>` at the end of the first line, then the script works fine if I change the `<br/>` after the input into a `<p>`.

**The following example works**

```
<span style="background-color:red">before input</span>
<input name="n1" value="test">
<p></p><span></span>
<span style="background-color:red">after input</span>
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmAjC/2/

Read more info about **self-closing tags** (and why `<p/>` isn't valid) here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/

Comment: It turns out that jquery doesn't like self-closing tags much :) thanks everybody.

Comment: Oddly enough, jQuery will honor self-closing `<p/>` tags when creating elements: http://jsfiddle.net/FG7qJ/